# Terraform: cannot traverse type VmwareDistributedVirtualSwitch

Tags: kubernetes, vmware, terraform, vcenter

Trying to setup [kubernetes-anywhere](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes-anywhere/blob/master/phase1/vsphere/README.md) for the first time, and I am having a challenge in getting terraform to use a distributed port group that I have setup in vCenter. The error message is:

```
* vsphere_virtual_machine.kubevm1: 1 error(s) occured:

* vsphere_virtual_machine.kubevm1: cannot traverse type VmwareDistributedVirtualSwitch
```

The pertinent terraform settings:

```
network_interface.#:                     "" => "1"
network_interface.0.ip_address:          "" => "<computed>"
network_interface.0.ipv4_address:        "" => "<computed>"
network_interface.0.ipv4_gateway:        "" => "<computed>"
network_interface.0.ipv4_prefix_length:  "" => "<computed>"
network_interface.0.ipv6_address:        "" => "<computed>"
network_interface.0.ipv6_gateway:        "" => "<computed>"
network_interface.0.ipv6_prefix_length:  "" => "<computed>"
network_interface.0.label:               "" => "Development/dvDevCluster/dvDHCP115"
network_interface.0.mac_address:         "" => "<computed>"
network_interface.0.subnet_mask:         "" => "<computed>"
```

Our vCenter's network inventory:
[distributed port group directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe82i.png)

We are trying to use the distributed port group dvDHCP115. Any help would be appreciated - I've spent way too long on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

Use the label "Development/dvDHCP115", not "Development/dvDevCluster/dvDHCP115"

Terraform does not appear to be able to handle the full path to the Port Group when it contains a Distributed Switch (e.g. dvDevCluster).

Comment: Did this actually end up using the port group in the distributed switch, or did it make a new one outside the switch?  Our net looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/vIrOu7L.png and I'm trying to get kubernetes anywhere to use the "VM Network" inside the distributed switch rather than the one outside, and it's not cooperating.

Comment: Cheated to solve my issue above by just creating a folder and moving the distributed switch into it, then copying what you did with this answer.  Not "happy" about it, but it works!